# Ng new command takes long time

Tags: angular-cli

I updated angular to newest. So now I have angular10. I made two projects without no problem with ng new command. But now when I tried create a new angular project for ng new proj_name it takes long time for installing packages.It completed with this error.

```
/ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."^2.8.6","coveralls":'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chalani\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-08T10_50_24_373Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

What should I do to create a new project???

Comment: can you execute the command (npm cache clean --force) thank again create new one.

Comment: Please like and accept my answer. Thanks in advance